# Customize the inventory Aging report in Ax 2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Actually am getting incorrect amount value for particular 1 item in invent aging report but that item have correct transaction amount value in other reports , I need to know where the business logic happen for this Invent aging report.

I tried to debug InventAgingReportLines classes and other classes but it wont work any ideas ?